# Valgrind massif combine snapshots

Tags: valgrind, massif

I'm trying to profile an application with `massif` tool. I run it with this command:

```
./valgrind.bin  --tool=massif --stacks=yes --heap=yes --trace-children=yes --vgdb=yes /usr/bin/agl_proxy
```

The application runs for a very long time. Generally, when application receives interrupt signal it would cleanly finish and `massif` would generate a profile file with many snapshots:

```
desc: --stacks=yes --heap=yes
cmd: /usr/bin/app
time_unit: i
#-----------
snapshot=0
#-----------
time=0
mem_heap_B=0
mem_heap_extra_B=0
mem_stacks_B=0
heap_tree=empty
#-----------
snapshot=1
#-----------
time=4501979
mem_heap_B=0
mem_heap_extra_B=0
mem_stacks_B=1480
heap_tree=empty
```

However, this particular application just dumps stock and hangs without properly exiting and thus *without* properly generating the result file. I can use `vgdb` to get a snapshot while the application is running. But it generates only one snapshot.

Is there any way to combine the snapshots? I've tried adding the snapshot into a file with `snapshot=#` header, but the [MassifVisualizer](https://github.com/KDE/massif-visualizer) complains about the format. Perhaps there is an option to combine them or some tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using vgdb, you can ask massif to dump all snapshots with the below monitor request:

```
all_snapshots [<filename>] requests to take all captured snapshots so far and save them in the given <filename> (default massif.vgdb.out).
```